# Action when clicking on an option in a select menu

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, html-select

I am programming a website with a map and a side panel, where I want some action to happend I chose an option in a select-menu.

This is my code:

```
<select id="optionList" onchange="display_div(document.getElementById('optionList').value);">
  <option selected="selected">Chose league</option>
  <option value="PL">Premier League</option>
  <option value="CH">Championship</option>
  <option value="L1">League 1</option>
  <option value="L2">League 2</option>
</select>
<p></p>
<div id="PL" style="display:none;">
  <select id="plTeamList" onchange="display_div2(document.getElementById('plTeamList').value);">
    <option selected="selected">Chose team</option>
    <option value="MUN">Manchester United</option>
    <option value="CHE">Chelsea</option>
    <option value="BOU">Bournemouth</option>
    <option value="NEW">Newcastle</option>
  </select>
  <div id="MUN" style="display:none" onclick="clickOnMUN()"> .... </div>
</div>
```

where I have a script with what happens when you choose Manchester United from the menu (it is plotting some popups in the map):

```
 function clickOnMUN() {
   var info = whichteam("MU"); // Finner ut hvilket lag som spiller, og info om stadion
   var marker = L.marker([info.substring(0, 5), info.substring(5, 10)]).addTo(map);

   marker.bindPopup(info.substring(10));
 }
```

This code is oddly not doing the script when I chose an option in the team-list.
The display_div-functions are only showing the options.

Comment: can you share `display_div` and `display_div2` functions?

Comment: Bournemouth and Newcastle!! - what sort of choice is that?

Sorry, I'm being flippant - try changing display_div and  display_div2 to alert() and see what happens.

And, to be very picky, it's 'Choose league', not Chose...

Comment: Oh... and you may need option_list.selectedIndex.value (check the syntax, but something like that)

Comment: The information you provided is not enough please elaborate your problem; if you can create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) it would be great ;

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see is the second "display_div" call... it says "display_div2" maybe a typo... but if it is the same as the first and only show the hidden div, removing the 2 should solve part of the problem. Also it could improve the code if you use some listeners for the clicks events instead of placing the function call inside the html tag. But this could be a version of your current code:

```js
function display_div( theDiv ) {
 console.log ( theDiv );
 $('#'+theDiv).css("display", "block" );
}

function clickOnTeamList(targ) {

 $('#status').html("clicked a team " + targ );
}
```

```css
p {
font-family: verdana;
font-size:12px;
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="optionList" onchange="display_div(document.getElementById('optionList').value)">
  <option selected="selected">Chose league </option>
  <option value="PL">Premier League • only option active</option>
  <option value="CH">Championship</option>
  <option value="L1">League 1</option>
  <option value="L2">League 2</option>
</select>
<p></p>

<div id="PL" style="display:none;">
  <select id="plTeamList" onchange="display_div(document.getElementById('plTeamList').value);">
    <option selected="selected">Chose team</option>
    <option value="MUN">Manchester United</option>
    <option value="CHE">Chelsea</option>
    <option value="BOU">Bournemouth</option>
    <option value="NEW">Newcastle</option>
  </select>
  
  <div id = "MUN" style="display:none" onclick="clickOnTeamList(' Manchester United')" ><p>Team: Manchester United</p></div>
  <div id = "CHE" style="display:none" onclick="clickOnTeamList('Chelsea')" ><p>Team: Chelsea</p></div>
  <div id = "BOU" style="display:none" onclick="clickOnTeamList('Bournemouth')" ><p>Team: Bournemouth</p></div>
  <div id = "NEW" style="display:none" onclick="clickOnTeamList('Newcastle')" ><p>Team: Newcastle</p></div>
  
</div>

<div id="status">___</div>
```